# stripe succed url not found

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am programming a payment system with stripe checkout in PHP, however when my payment is completed and it has to redirect me to the successful payment url I get the following error: Not Acceptable!
An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

I clarify that this happens when my application is already implemented on a hosting (I am using hostgator), it works correctly on my computer (I am using XAMPP).

This code handles the Checkout Session creation process with the Stripe PHP SDK library:

```
<?php

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dirs.php');
require_once VENDOR_PATH . "/autoload.php";
require_once MODELS_PATH . "/Curso.php";

use \Stripe\StripeClient;
use \Models\Curso;

// Set content type to JSON 
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$datos = json_decode($json, true);

$idCurso = $datos['id_curso'];
$nombreCurso = $datos['nombre'];
$precioTotal = $datos['total'];


// Set API key
$stripe = new StripeClient(STRIPE_API_KEY);

$response = array(
    'status' => 0,
    'error' => array(
        'message' => 'Invalid Request!'
    )
);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $input = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $request = json_decode($input);
}

if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}

if (!empty($request->createCheckoutSession)) {
    // Create new Checkout Session for the order
    try {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $checkout_session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
            'line_items' => [
                [
                    'price_data' => [
                        'unit_amount' => round($precioTotal * 100, 2),
                        'currency' => "mxn",
                        'product_data' => [
                            'name' => $nombreCurso,
                            'metadata' => [
                                'pro_id' => "$idCurso"
                            ],
                            "images" => [
                                'https://e838-2806-10ae-19-172d-69e0-414a-4c9e-c433.ngrok-free.app/administrador/assents/cursos/El-2024-Campa-as-comunicaci-n-y-crisis-pol-ticas.png'
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                    'quantity' => 1
                ]

            ],
        
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'success_url' => 'https://marisainforma.mx/PagosStripe/prueba.php?id_curso='. $idCurso. '&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            'cancel_url' =>"https://marisainforma.mx/PagosStripe/payment-cancel.php",
        ]);
      
        
        //header("Location: " . $checkout_session->url);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $api_error = $e->getMessage();
    }

    if (empty($api_error) && $checkout_session) {
        $response = array(
            'status' => 1,
            'message' => 'Checkout Session created successfully!',
            'sessionId' => $checkout_session->id
        );
    } else {
        $response = array(
            'status' => 0,
            'error' => array(
                'message' => 'Checkout Session creation failed! ' . $api_error
            )
        );
    }
}

// Return response
echo json_encode($response);
```

this is the Success Page URL when the payment is completed.

```
<?php
// Set content type to JSON 
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dirs.php');
require_once CONFIG_PATH . "funciones.php";
require_once CONFIG_PATH . "database.php";
require_once MODELS_PATH . "Curso.php";
require_once MODELS_PATH . "Compra.php";
require_once MODELS_PATH . "Correo.php";
require_once VENDOR_PATH . "autoload.php";

use Config\Conectar;
use Models\Curso;
use Models\Compra;
use Models\Correo;
use Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException;
use Stripe\StripeClient;



$db = new Conectar();
$con = $db->conexion();
$curso = new Curso();



$payment_id = $statusMsg = '';
$status = 'error';


// Check whether stripe checkout session is not empty 
if (!empty($_GET['session_id'])) {

    $session_id = $_GET['session_id'];
    $id_curso = $_GET['id_curso'];

    // Fetch transaction data from the database if already exists 
    $sqlQ = sprintf("SELECT * FROM compras_stripe WHERE stripe_checkout_session_id = '%s'", $session_id);
    $result = $con->query($sqlQ);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // Transaction details 
        $transData = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $payment_id = $transData['id'];
        $transactionID = $transData['id_transaccion'];
        $paidAmount = $transData['total_compra'];
        $payment_status = $transData['estatus'];
        $customer_name = $transData['nombre_comprador'];
        $customer_email = $transData['nombre_comprador'];
        $status = 'success';
        $statusMsg = 'Your Payment has been Successful!';
    } else {
        // Include the Stripe PHP library 
        // Set API key 
        $stripe = new StripeClient(STRIPE_API_KEY);

        // Fetch the Checkout Session to display the JSON result on the success page 
        try {
            $checkout_session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->retrieve($session_id);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $api_error = $e->getMessage();
        }

        if (empty($api_error) && $checkout_session) {
            // Get customer details 
            $customer_details = $checkout_session->customer_details;

            // Retrieve the details of a PaymentIntent 

            try {
                $paymentIntent = $stripe->paymentIntents->retrieve($checkout_session->payment_intent);
            } catch (ApiErrorException $e) {
                $api_error = $e->getMessage();
            }


            if (empty($api_error) && $paymentIntent) {
                // Check whether the payment was successful 
                if (!empty($paymentIntent) && $paymentIntent->status == 'succeeded') {
                    // Transaction details 

                    $transactionID = $paymentIntent->latest_charge;
                    $paidAmount = $paymentIntent->amount;
                    $paidAmount = ($paidAmount / 100);
                    $payment_status = $paymentIntent->status;

                    // Customer info 
                    $customer_name = $customer_email = '';
                    if (!empty($customer_details)) {
                        $customer_name = !empty($customer_details->name) ? $customer_details->name : '';
                        $customer_email = !empty($customer_details->email) ? $customer_details->email : '';
                    }

                    $fecha = date("Y-m-d");
                    $hora = date("H:i:s");

                    // Check if any transaction data is exists already with the same TXN ID 
                    $db_session_id = $session_id;
                    $sqlQ = sprintf("SELECT * FROM compras_stripe WHERE stripe_checkout_session_id = '%s'", $db_session_id);
                    $result = $con->query($sqlQ);
                    $prevRow = $result->fetch_assoc();

                    if (!empty($prevRow)) {
                        $payment_id = $prevRow['id'];
                    } else {
                        // Insert transaction data into the database 

                        $payment_status = ($payment_status === "succeeded") ? "Aprobado" : "No aprobado";
                        $compra = new Compra();
                        $stmt = $compra->insertarCompraTargeta($customer_name, $customer_email, $id_curso, $paidAmount, $transactionID, $payment_status, "Stripe", $session_id, $fecha, $hora);

                        if ($stmt) {
                            $payment_id = 100;
                        }
                    }
                    $status = 'success';
                    $statusMsg = 'Tu pago a sido exitoso!';
                } else {
                    $statusMsg = "La transaccion a fallado!";
                }
            } else {
                $statusMsg = "Unable to fetch the transaction details! $api_error";
            }
        } else {
            $statusMsg = "Invalid Transaction! $api_error";
        }
    }
} else {
    $statusMsg = "Invalid Request!";
}

if (!empty($payment_id)) {

    //Obtener los datos de la reunion
    $curso = new Curso();

    //Obtenemos los datos de la reunion del curso 
    $datosCurso1 = $curso->obtenerCursoPorID($id_curso);
    $fechaCurso = $datosCurso1['fechaInicio'];
    $horaCurso = $datosCurso1["horaInicio"];
    $linkReunionCurso = $datosCurso1['link_zoom'];
    $precioCurso = $datosCurso1['precio'];
    $descuentoCurso = $datosCurso1['descuento'];
    $nombreCurso = $datosCurso1['nombreCurso'];
    $contraseniaReunionCurso = $datosCurso1['contrasenia_zoom'];

    //Agregamos un comprador para el curso 
    $curso->insertarAsistente($id_curso);

    $datosCorreo = array(
        'comprador' => array(
            "nombre" => $customer_name,
            "estatus" => $payment_status,
            "metodo" => "Stripe",
            "fecha" => $fecha,
            "hora" => $hora,
            "total" => $paidAmount
        ),

        "cursos" => array(
            array(
                "folio" => $transactionID,
                "nombreCurso" => $nombreCurso,
                "linkReunion" => $linkReunionCurso,
                "contrasenia" => $contraseniaReunionCurso,
                "fechaInicio" => $fechaCurso,
                "horaInicio" => $horaCurso,
                "precio" => $precioCurso,
                "descuento" => $descuentoCurso,
                "precioDescuento" => floatval($precioCurso - $descuentoCurso),
            )
        )
    );


    //Enviar correo
    $correo = new Correo();
    $correo->enviarCorreoDeCompra($customer_email, $datosCorreo);
    header("Location: completado.php?id1=" . $id_curso);
} else { 
    echo "Error en el pago!";
    echo $statusMsg;
}
```

I hope you can help me

I tried changing the test url without parameters, which redirected to a blank page but nothing worked

Comment: This looks like an issue when it returns back to your success URL "https://marisainforma.mx/PagosStripe/prueba.php?id_curso='. $idCurso. '&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}'". How does the request look like in Chrome console? You would want to curl your own success URL with a POST request first to test its availability.